# How does mass of magnet with current-flowing wire inside change?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

We just did an experiment where we put a coil inside of a magnet and let certain current run through the coil and measure the mass change of the magnet.

I have looked/researched in textbook and google and hasn't been able to come up with the solution of how the mass change of the magnet is possible.

Is there any known effects with names or an explanation to how that is possible?

Comment: You didn't measure a mass change (which does exist but is far too small for you to measure), but a force between the magnet and the coil.

Comment: yea thats what I just came up with. Either the attraction or repulsion between the coil and the magnet either increases or decreases the weight of the magnet due to the change of the net force.